# Why I obtain this exception into a Spring Data JPA native SQL query? IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am not so into **Spring Data JPA** (that uses **Hibernate 4.3.11.Final**) and I have the following situation.

I have this SQL query (that performed directly into MySql works fine), the query simply finds all the hotels registered into the **accomodation** table that are into a specific range from a selected point:

```
SET @fiumicino = GeomFromText('POINT(41.768835 12.247658)'); 

SELECT *
FROM accomodation a
WHERE earth_circle_distance(@fiumicino, a.geographical_position) < 7
```

So as you can see in the previus code this query have 2 parameters:

- **@fiumicino**: that is a MySqk Spatial **POINT** object.
- 7: that simply is a range.

Ok, it works fine...

So I tryied to convert it into a **native SQL query** into my **Spring Data JPA** repository interface, I have done:

```
@Repository
public interface AccomodationDAO extends JpaRepository<Accomodation, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM accomodation a WHERE earth_circle_distance(?0, a.geographical_position) < ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Accomodation findByRange(Point location, int range);

}
```

Basically I have replaced the **@fiumicino** with the **?0** parameter and the **7** value of the distance range with **?1**.

Then I have created this simple unit test method:

```
@Test
public void findByRangeTest() throws ParseException {

    System.out.println("findByRangeTest() START");

    Accomodation accomodation = null;

    int range = 7;

    double lat = 41.768835;
    double lon = 12.247658;

    Point location = GisUtils.buildGeometry(lat, lon);

    accomodation = accomodationDAO.findByRange(location, range);

    assert(accomodation != null);

    System.out.println("findByRangeTest() END");

}
```

The problem is that when this method perform the **findByRange()** method I obtain the following exception into my stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findByRange(Unknown Source)
    at com.betrivius.test.dao.DAOTest.findByRangeTest(DAOTest.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:188)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 36 more
```

So, what exactly means this excetpion? Why it referer to a parameter **with position [2]** if in my query I only have 2 params **?0**, and **?1** ?

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bind statements indexes start with 1.

This should work:

```
@Repository
public interface AccomodationDAO extends JpaRepository<Accomodation, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM accomodation a WHERE earth_circle_distance(?1, a.geographical_position) < ?2", nativeQuery = true)
Accomodation findByRange(Point location, int range);

}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: "In bind statements indexes start with 1."
 is not explicitely indicated in the doc you refer.  It may be supposed by the examples

Comment: Provided as an example.